# Phase-frequency detector not used in a PLL

Tags: detection, phase

My application: I need to output a voltage based on a phase difference between two input signals (a voltage and a current). It seems that a phase-frequency detector will do exactly this but I have hardly seen any examples where people have used these outside of Phase locked loop applications.

What else do I need to consider before trying this out? Are there any pitfalls to using a PFD for my application or will it work? I need both positive and negative output voltage based on the sign of the phase difference.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the voltage and the current to digital signals, using analog comparators. Then run both those digital signals into an exclusive-or gate.

There will be problems with that, such as ambiguity.

Comment: I thought about this but that won't give me a negative output. I need to know which signal is leading and an XOR will only tell me if they are different.